# xml to tsql select statement returns only one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need to build an table using an xml.

This is my xml:

```
<root>
  <Child>c1</Child>
  <Child>c2</Child>
  <Child>c3</Child>
  <Child>c4</Child>
  <ID>9908</ID>
</root>
```

My try:

```
DECLARE @ixml INT,
@Param  VARCHAR(max)='<root>
  <Child>c1</Child>
  <Child>c2</Child>
  <Child>c3</Child>
  <Child>c4</Child>
  <ID>9908</ID>
</root>'


 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument  @ixml OUTPUT, @Param  

    Select Child,ID
    FROM OPENXML(@ixml, 'root')
    WITH 
    (
        Child [nVARCHAR](max) 'Child',  
        ID [INT] 'ID'
    ) 


----------
```

Actual output :

```
Child  |    ID
c1     |    9908
```

Expected Output:

```
Child  |    ID
c1     |    9908
c2     |    9908
c3     |    9908
c4     |    9908
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I would suggest that you try just selecting the `Child` elements, then adding the `ID` after you have that right

Comment: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @ixml INT,
@Param  VARCHAR(max)='<root>
  <Child>c1</Child>
  <Child>c2</Child>
  <Child>c3</Child>
  <Child>c4</Child>
  <ID>9908</ID>
</root>'


 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument  @ixml OUTPUT, @Param  

Select Child, ID
FROM OPENXML(@ixml, '/root/Child')
WITH 
(
    Child [nVARCHAR](max) '.', ID [int]   '../ID'
)
```

Comment: Great. However, keep in mind, that you should remove the xml reference when you are finished (exec sp_xml_removedocument @ixml;)

Comment: Due to the cumbersome way of working with these stored procedures (including the possibility to forget to close documents etc), you should steer clear of these and instead use the new way of working with XML as outlined in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with declaring the `@Param` as an XML type, and using XPath expressions in [`nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) and [`value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type), you would get:

```sql
DECLARE @Param XML='<root>
  <Child>c1</Child>
  <Child>c2</Child>
  <Child>c3</Child>
  <Child>c4</Child>
  <ID>9908</ID>
</root>'

SELECT
    Child=n.v.value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(128)'),
    ID=n.v.value('../ID[1]','INT')
FROM
    @Param.nodes('root/Child') AS n(v);
```

With the expected result.

---

A slightly better version (with input from [@Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887576/xml-to-tsql-select-statement-returns-only-one-row/46887862#comment80728388_46887862)), with direct selection of `/root/ID` instead of backward navigation in the XPath expression:

```
SELECT
    Child=n.v.value('.[1]','NVARCHAR(128)'),
    ID=@Param.value('(/root/ID/text())[1]','INT')
FROM
    @Param.nodes('root/Child') AS n(v);
```

Comment: Good answer, plused it... For performance you might keep in mind, that backward navigation is a draw back and fetching `text()` is slightly faster than the simple `ID[1]`. I'd use `SELECT ID=@Param.value('(/root/ID/text())[1]','int'), Child=n.v.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(128)') FROM ...`

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you for the hint, worked that in my answer.